# cleaning data graph in real time

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a graph in real time...

My code is

```
 public class Chart_Broadcaster
    {
        public class LineChart
        {
            [JsonProperty("lineChartData")]
            private int[] lineChartData;
            [JsonProperty("colorString")]
            private string colorString;

            [JsonProperty("hora")]
            private string[] hora = new string[60];

            public void SetLineChartData()
            {
                //Suppose we have a list of 60 items.
                using (ZigBeeContext db = new ZigBeeContext())
                {
                    var lista = (from p in db.Medidas
                                 orderby p.FechaHora descending
                                 select p
                                 ).ToList();

                    lineChartData = db.Medidas.Select(p => p.Temperatura).Cast<int>().ToArray();
                    hora = db.Medidas.Select(p => p.FechaHora).Cast<string>().ToArray();

                }
            }
        }

        public class TemperatureUpdate
        {


            [JsonProperty("DashboardTemperatureResult")]
            private List<DashboardTemperatureResult> temp;

            public void TakeLastTemp()
            {

                using (ZigBeeContext db = new ZigBeeContext())
                {

                    var result = db.Empresas.Include("Dispositivos.Medidas").ToList();
                    List<DashboardTemperatureResult> lis = new List<DashboardTemperatureResult>();
                    foreach (var item in result.SelectMany(x => x.Dispositivos))
                    {
                        if (item.Medidas.OrderBy(y => y.FechaHora).Any())
                            lis.Add(new DashboardTemperatureResult
                            {
                                DispositivoId = item.Medidas.OrderBy(y => y.FechaHora).LastOrDefault().DispositivoID,
                                Empresa = item.Medidas.OrderBy(y => y.FechaHora).LastOrDefault().Dispositivo.Empresa.Nombre,
                                Temperature = item.Medidas.OrderBy(y => y.FechaHora).LastOrDefault().Temperatura
                            });

                    }


                    temp = lis;
                }
            }
        }




 var lineChartData = {

            datasets: [
                {
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    //backgroundColor: "#000000",
                    borderColor: "rgba(125,0,0,0)",
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#7FFF00",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 1,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data: [0]
                }
            ]

        }

        function UpdateLineChart(data) {

            lineChartData.labels = data.hora;
            var canvasForLineChart = document.getElementById("canvasForLineChart");
            var context2DLine = canvasForLineChart.getContext("2d");
            new Chart(context2DLine).Line(lineChartData);
        }
```

my graph is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbzaC.png)

I have a lot of data on my chart , not as clean , with all records from my database ,

as I do to clean each x time.